# squirrelMail 1.5.2 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, email

I have a Macpro, Iphone,Ipad, and a windows machine at work.  The iphone and ipad are configured for IMAP and works great.  The windows machine using firefox is a web address to log in.  All those mentioned work great except my ubuntu desktop 20.04.  It also uses the same web address as the windows machine, but upon replying to an email, it places the sent mail in my inbox instead. The recipient never gets it either. I can't say that it is a config error, cause all the other machines work properly.  I use Firefox on all machines that require http webmail access to the squirrelMail site.Anyone seen this problem before.  I am also open to suggestions.  Thanks!